# sql query from multiple random tables

Tags: sqlite

i have 3 tables

table 1( one id to one name)

```
ID|name

1| john

2|mike

3|olga

4|juliet
```

table 2 ()

```
ID|adress

1|xxx

1|yyy

2|xx

2|z

3|xxx

3|yy
```

table 3 ()

```
address|buildings

xxx|flat

xxx|building

z|flat

z|building

z|park

z|lot

yy|building

yy|park
```

i wish to find the `name` of those wanting to stay at both `building` and `flat`, all values are random so i can only search with buildings, i have already managed to query for only one type of buildings but i am missing something as to validate the needed AND

Comment: And the correct result for your sample data should be?

Comment: as per @forpas code the correct result would be (john,mike,olga). [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3J6i3NvQWN3w6gnsajzi1X/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join all 3 tables and group by `name`:

```
SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.address = t2.address
WHERE t3.buildings IN ('building', 'flat')
GROUP BY t1.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t3.buildings) = 2
```